# Get error 500 while pass some properties of object in ajax from view to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I use web service with ajax call and I want save web service output in database.but when get output from web service in success option, does not execute ajax part in success and gives error 500:
POST http://localhost:36369/Crises/MapService 500 (Internal Server Error)   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
How can I solve it?

this is view ajax:

```
        $.each(CrisisSites, function (idx, value) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://map.ir/search/v2',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                     'x-api-key': 'apikey'
                },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType:'JSON',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'text': value.Site,


                }),

                success: function (data) {
                    dest.push(data.value[0].geom.coordinates.reverse());
                    value.Latitude = dest[0][0];
                    value.Longitude = dest[0][1];

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Crises/MapService',
                        method: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ id: value.Id, latitude: value.Latitude, longitude: 
                        value.Longitude, site: value.Site }),
                        success:function(result)
                         {
                            alert("success");

                         }

                          }); 

                }
```

this is controller action:

```
   public ActionResult MapService(int id,double latitude,double longitude, 
    string site)
    {

        CrisisSite CrisisSite = new CrisisSite();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                var crisisId = db.CrisisSite.ToList().Max().Id;
                crisisId = crisisId + 1;
                CrisisSite.Site = site;
                CrisisSite.Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(latitude);
                CrisisSite.Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(longitude);
                db.CrisisSite.Add(CrisisSite);
                db.SaveChanges();

        }

        return Json(CrisisSite,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting your data to your action so your action must be decorated with `HttpPost`. Plus, your data must be an object in your action method and for that reason, you should remove the `JSON.stringify` in your ajax method.

create a class for receiving post data like this :

```
public class LocationInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
}
```

change your ajax method :

```
$.each(CrisisSites, function (idx, value) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://map.ir/search/v2',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                 'x-api-key': 'apikey'
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType:'JSON',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'text': value.Site,


            }),

            success: function (data) {
                dest.push(data.value[0].geom.coordinates.reverse());
                value.Latitude = dest[0][0];
                value.Longitude = dest[0][1];

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Crises/MapService',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: { id: value.Id, latitude: value.Latitude, longitude: 
                    value.Longitude, site: value.Site },
                    success:function(result)
                     {
                        alert("success");

                     }

                      }); 

            }
```

and your action method like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MapService(LocationInfo data)
{

    CrisisSite CrisisSite = new CrisisSite();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

            var crisisId = db.CrisisSite.ToList().Max().Id;
            crisisId = crisisId + 1;
            CrisisSite.Site = data.Site;
            CrisisSite.Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Latitude);
            CrisisSite.Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Longitude);
            db.CrisisSite.Add(CrisisSite);
            db.SaveChanges();

    }

    return Json(CrisisSite,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    //return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. error resolved, but receive null value for  Latitude and Longitude in controller action. while they have value in ajax.

Comment: you're welcome. check their value in your success method with `console.log(value.Latitude)` and `console.log(value.Longitude)` after they've got value. if your `Id` and `Site` have got value then it means `Latitude` and `Longitude` have no value in your success method or they couldn't be converted to `double` type!

Comment: I set data type of latitude and longitude to decimal(9,6). in viewmodel I set them to decimal too. I put console.log(value.Latitude) and console.log(value.Longitude) in success method, but console displays undefined.

Comment: if your console shows undefined data, that means this line `dest.push(data.value[0].geom.coordinates.reverse());` not working well.

Comment: before ajax in success method dest has correct values. I change datatype of lat and long in sql to float. but I still get undefined in console. I put alert(value.Latitude) in success method and it returns Latitude correctly. What should I do now to fix the problem?

Comment: data in ajax has correct Latitude and Longitude,too.

Comment: in controller action in part Modelstate.Isvalid I get error for Latitude:                      "The value '35.8332410269314'   is not valid for Latitude."

Comment: this because your data conversion is not OK. If you change them to string type, everything will be fine.